# trying to avoid value attribute to stringify object

Tags: angularjs, json, object, angularjs-ng-repeat

So here is the deal, im getting different objects from ajax request ($scope.productos - $scope.ofertas) and then using ng-foreach for both to show them so user can select multiple items (stored in $pedidoForm.productos and
pedidoForm.ofertas) and this selected items dinamically show up below with another ng-repeat showing the 'nombre' property and adding another new property and value with input but the atribute VALUE is automatically converting any object into a string, resulting in a "{property: value}" so i cant read the property correctly

```
            <div class="row">
            <span>Productos</span>
            <select class="selectpicker" ng-model="pedidoForm.productos" ng-change=parse(pedidoForm.productos) multiple>
                <option ng-repeat="producto in productos" value="{{producto}}"> {{producto.nombre}} 
                </option>
            </select>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
            <span>Ofertas</span>
            <select class="selectpicker" ng-model="pedidoForm.ofertas" ng-change="test(pedidoForm)"  multiple>
                <option ng-repeat="oferta in ofertas" value="{{oferta}}"> {{oferta.nombre}} </option>
            </select>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

as I understand you need to select an object, but HTML5 *select* tag supports only string values. So, try to use *ng-options* directive:

```
<div class="row">
  <span>Productos</span>
  <select class="selectpicker" 
          multiple
          ng-model="pedidoForm.productos" 
          ng-change="parse(pedidoForm.productos)"
          ng-options="producto as producto.nombre for producto in productos track by producto.nombre">
  </select>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <span>Ofertas</span>
  <select class="selectpicker" 
          multiple
          ng-model="pedidoForm.ofertas" 
          ng-change="test(pedidoForm)"
          ng-options="oferta as oferta.nombre for oferta in ofertas track by oferta.nombre">
  </select>
</div>
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/jl1cayWXif7fukQRviTw?p=preview

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, ng-options works like a charm!